# Difference between SSL certificates showing with name in browser bar and without

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ssl, certificate

I noticed Chrome shows the owner of a SSL-certificate only in some cases in the adressbar. What is the difference between these types of certificates.
Here is an example:

**With company**

[image]

**Without company**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With company is present when the site owner has opted for an EV (Extended Validation) Certificate.

The certificate authority (company that provides the certificate) goes to extra effort to confirm the identify of the business/owner (for an extra fee), whereas non-ev certificates can be provided merely by proving you having control over the domain.